# Create filepath for email attachment

Tags: python, python-3.x, filepath, email-attachments

Using Python 3 and a Pi4, I generate .csv files with names based on the time & date; for example: `0715200732.csv`.

I want to send this file as an attachment to an email.  In sending the email & attachment, if I explicitly describe the file path & filename as, for example:

```
fname = 0715200715
filename = "/home/pi/data/0715200715.csv"  # followed by
attachment = open(filename,'rb')
```

The received email shows the attachment as an Excel file that can be directly opened with Excel.

But, if I attempt to "build" the path by using, for example,

```
fname =  0715200715
path = os.path.dirname('/home/pi/data/')
filename = os.path.join(path, fname + '.csv')
attachment = open(filename, 'rb')
```

The attachment in the received email is shown only as a "Mail Attachment", with the .csv extension missing.  I have to rename the file with the .csv extension to open it with Excel.

I have tried dozens of variant ways to create the filename so that the received email has the attachment showing as a .csv file, without success.

Comment: Hello DennisD, you need to show the part of the code where you send the email. The two code snippets you show above are equivalent (with the only difference that one defines a "path" variable).

Comment: cidermole: the code on either side of the snippets are identical.  The problem is how to "build" the file path so that--to the attachment statement--it looks identical to the first example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a small error in the path creation, which is probably messing up the mail attachment

when you say

`path = os.path.dirname('/home/pi/data')`

path = '/home/pi'  not '/home/pi/data'

so when you .join with your filename the wrong path is generated.

You should have gotten a `OSError` for file not found.  The fact that you didn't indicates to me that something else is happening in your code that is missing from this example.  Please provide more code if you want more help.  Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  To be clear, I save the "MMDDYYTTTT.csv" files I generate in a folder named "data".  Don't I need the /data/ in the path statement?  I don't receive any OS errors and the file IS sent to me, but it simply lacks the .csv file extension.

Comment: You DO need the /data/, the problem is ```os.path.dirname``` truncates the last item.  Just let ```path``` variable = <path-to-csv-files>